# Redirecting route in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

This is ok:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
```

But I want to redirect incoming requests to ApiFolder folder's class
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your namespace in your route configuration:

```
var r = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional },
);
if( r.DataTokens == null ){
  r.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
}
r.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] {"ApiFolder"};
```

Comment: r.DateTokens is null, and I can't set ["Namespaces"].

Comment: You should should do a `null`-check and instantiate a new `RouteValueDictionary` if it is `null`. I edited my answer.

Comment: `Property or indexer System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRoute.DataTokens cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` DataTokens property is read only !

Comment: Hm, you're right, that actually doesn't work. From what I see, this feature is not supported with MapHttpRoute

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth's suggestion wont work as stated in the comments.

However you can write your own implementation of IHttpControllerSelector and only assign it when you map the api routes. I used the implementation in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx) as a base and modified it.

Then its just the small issue of replacing the default selector after mapping the route in WebApiConfig like this (where CustomControllerSelector is my implementation):

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var apiRoute = configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controllerNamespace = "api" }
        );

        configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomControllerSelector(configuration));
    }
```