# ASP.NET MVC 5 Routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have two types of controllers:

[1] Inherited from BaseController (namespace: Foo.Bar.Controllers)

[2] Inherited from BaseAPIController (namespace: Foo.Bar.Controllers.API)

How I can route all /api/{controller}/{action} requests to controllers [2] and all other request to controllers [1] ?

note: I don't use Web API framework, just MVC 5

Answer (score 0):

My solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609561/redirecting-route-in-asp-net-webapi/21893557#21893557) should work, I don't think the routing logic is specific to WebAPI.

Basically write a custom IHttpControllerSelector that takes custom namespaces in consideration.